# Is there a word for something someone is known for?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for something that someone is particularly known for. e.g. a song that a singer always is asked to sing

Comment: As soon as I posted my question I thought of a possible answer: "signature song"

Comment: We've also **chef-d'oeuvre** which essentially has been appropriated into English to mean _masterpiece_ but is not confined to music or even the arts, & can be used to describe Einstein's Mass-Energy Equivalence just as easily as can it be used to describe Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata.

Comment: It's not a single word, but probably the most widely used phrase in that context is 'claim to fame'.

Answer (score 12):

***Signature*** is the answer. Both as a count noun and an adjective.

> *[count noun]* something (such as a quality or feature) that is closely associated with someone or something — usually singular
>
> *Her latest movie includes the humor and fast pace that have become her signature.*
>
> *[adjective]* closely associated with someone or something : making a person or thing easy to recognize
>
> *the chef's signature dish* 
>       *“Respect” is her signature song/tune.* 
>       *The director's new movie is a return to his signature style.*
>
> <sup>http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/signature</sup>

Answer (score 6):

**Trademark**: A distinctive characteristic by which a person or thing comes to be known.

E.g. (Lifted from @ermanen)...

...1-Her latest movie includes the humor and fast pace that have become her *trademark*.

2-The shuffle and snicker that became the comedian's trademark.

*Though "***signature***" would be the first thought for something that someone is particularly known for.*

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, I think the term "magnum opus" is appropriate.  According to Merriam-Webster the definition of magnum opus is as follows.

[magnum opus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magnum%20opus) - noun - a great work; especially :  the greatest achievement of an artist or writer.

Comment: I'd have difficulty calling a song of a few minutes a "magnum opus", however remarkable it might be.

Answer (score -2):

epitome

the typical or highest example of a stated quality, as shown by a particular person or thing:
Even now in her sixties, she is the epitome of French elegance.

src: Cambridge online

Also the characteristic would be antonomasia

:  the use of a proper name to designate a member of a class (as a Solomon for a wise ruler); also :  the use of an epithet or title in place of a proper name (as the Bard for Shakespeare)